# How do I Capture The First N words in a String? Using Regex?

Tags: regex

I have a regex that looks like this (all word characters plus underscore and dash):

```
/[\w\-_]+/gm
```

And an input that looks like this:

```
This is a cat. It is fat. That is a dog. It looks like a log. Fat-cat dog_log
```

It is correctly matching all the words, skipping the whitespace and punctuations. But I only want to get the first 3 words.  I thought I could just add `{1,3}` to the end of the regex and get this result but this gives an error. The regex tester I used can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/Ec1IAH/1

Comment: Would you want to match "This is a" or "This" and "is" and "a"?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: The first 3 words never contain any punctuations?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:[\w-]+[^\w-]+){2}[\w-]+
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ec1IAH/5)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - matches the start of the line
- `(?:[\w-]+[^\w-]+){2}`

  - `[\w-]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a word character or `-`
  - `[^\w-]*` - matches 1+ occurrences of all the characters which are either non-word characters or not a `-` i.e, matches every character other than alphabets, numbers, underscore and `-`
  - `{2}` - repeat the above 2 steps 2 times
- `[\w-]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a word character or `-`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
^\w+(?:-\w+)*(?:\s+\w+(?:-\w+)*){2}
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/XAZLBO/1)

**Regex short circuit**:

[image]

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){2}                     end of grouping
```